# Fill-down formula vs array formula vs table formula

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have the following Excel table:

[image]

To create a new column for **Full Name**, what is the suggested or more common way to do it:

1. Doing a scalar formula and then clicking to fill-down such as shown [here](https://gyazo.com/08919c11660c9002c0fc3411d7a49749); or
2. Doing an array formula such as shown [here](https://gyazo.com/3ed5f6254a8d5a1e49b3a396a866804d).
3. Or I suppose converting it into a table object and then applying a row formula such as shown [here](https://gyazo.com/39d7967df0a8eb4fff1151b6dcd4f1af). Oddly though, it doesn't automatically fill down the column and you have to fill-down such as in step 1.

Are there any guides on what the suggested way to work with this stuff is? I can't find much on the official Excel site. What is the way this is usually done?

Comment: I prefer option 2 (since the mouse isn't needed - as there's no keyboard shortcut for fill down) although its only available in later versions of Excel, and try to avoid tables since, like conditional formatting, they can have an adverse effect on performance. Btw the non autofill observed in option 3 is a configurable setting - press Alt + T, then A, and click the _AutoFormat As You Type_ tab, the 3rd option there determines whether formulae fill down or not

Comment: All three are valid and useful methods.  Which one to use will depend on your specific circumstances.  FWIW, general advice to avoid Tables is bad advice.  Use them when it makes sense to, don't when it doesn't

Comment: @chrisneilsen what would be an example where a table wouldn't make sense? Perhaps you'd want to post an answer showing where it makes sense to use which?

Comment: Well, as SpectralInstance kind of said, over use of tables can slow down your workbook.  Another example is where you _want_ to use Spill formulas.   Spills and Tables don't mix well

Answer (score -1):

Use the Left, Right, and Mid functions that use Search. These are always dynamic.